# Python and logging: best practice with .exe

Tags: python, logging, pyinstaller

I have a software in Python and I compiled it with pyinstaller.

I would like, if any error occurs, to save the logs. Which do you think is the best practice to do so in an exe by keeping the software fast, portable and smart?

Comment: What's wront with the stdlib's logging module ? https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Comment: i think the issue although maybe not worded as well as it could be, is that he wants to catch errors that may not be expected (and hence not guarded against with `try: catch:`) and save the traceback to see what went wrong and where

Answer (score 0):

I have a class written for this [here](https://github.com/JamesGKent/python-tkwidgets/blob/master/debuglogger.py)

```
import logging
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

__all__ = ["logging",
           "StreamToLogger",
           "Debug_Logger"]
 
class StreamToLogger(object):
    def __init__(self, logger, log_level=logging.INFO):
        self.logger = logger
        self.log_level = log_level
        self.error_types = ["AssertionError", "AttributeError",
                            "EOFError", "FloatingPointError",
                            "GeneratorExit", "ImportError",
                            "IndexError", "KeyError",
                            "KeyboardInterrupt", "MemoryError",
                            "NameError", "NotImplementedError",
                            "OSError", "OverflowError",
                            "ReferenceError", "RuntimeError",
                            "StopIteration", "SyntaxError",
                            "IndentationError", "TabError",
                            "SystemError", #"SystemExit", #included for completeness, but illogical to log a normal exit
                            "TypeError", "UnboundLocalError",
                            "UnicodeError", "UnicodeEncodeError",
                            "UnicodeDecodeError", "UnicodeTranslateError",
                            "ValueError", "ZeroDivisionError",
                            "EnvironmentError", "IOError",
                            "WindowsError", "BlockingIOError",
                            "ChildProcessError", "ConnectionError",
                            "BrokenPipeError", "ConnectionAbortedError",
                            "ConnectionRefusedError", "ConnectionResetError",
                            "FileExistsError", "FileNotFoundError",
                            "InterruptedError", "IsADirectoryError",
                            "NotADirectoryError", "PermissionError",
                            "ProcessLookupError", "TimeoutError",]

    def write(self, buf):
        for line in buf.rstrip().splitlines():
            self.logger.log(self.log_level, line.rstrip())
        for entry in self.error_types:
            if entry in str(buf):
                root = tk.Tk()
                root.withdraw()
                messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "An error has occured,\ncheck error log")
                root.destroy()

    def flush(self):
        pass

class DebugLogger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.GUI = tk.Toplevel()
        self.GUI.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.GUI.withdraw)
        self.GUI.title("Debug Console")

        self.textbox = ScrolledText(self.GUI)
        self.textbox.configure(state = "disabled")
        self.textbox.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
        self.GUI.focus()

    def write(self, buf):
        self.textbox.configure(state = "normal")
        self.textbox.insert(tk.END, str(buf))
        self.textbox.configure(state = "disabled")
        self.textbox.see("end")

    def flush(self):
        pass
```

which you could use like so:

```
import logging, sys
if ("-d" in sys.argv) or ("-D" in sys.argv):
  debugger = Debug_Logger()
  sys.stdout = debugger
  sys.stderr = debugger
else:
  logdir = os.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\applicationame\\"
  if not os.path.isdir(logdir):
    os.makedirs(logdir)
  logfile = logdir + "applicationname.log"
  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s', filename=logfile, filemode='w')
  sys.stdout = StreamToLogger(logging.getLogger('STDOUT'), logging.INFO) 
  sys.stderr = StreamToLogger(logging.getLogger('STDERR'), logging.ERROR)
```

and this will catch all exceptions and tracebacks and save them into the file (with time and date) and also any output left in the program such as print statements. Also if you start the program with a flag on the command line (-d) a window tkinter window is shown to shouw the traceback in realtime even once compiled (i have tested with cx_Freeze)

Comment: my apologies, should be fixed now. note that github version has been tweaked, now colours the stdout blue and stderr red in the interactive window.

Answer (score -1):

I would log by opening a file in append mode 'a'. 
A simple debug function could look like this:

```
def debug(x):
    fd = open("log.txt","a")
    fd.write(time.ctime() + "\t" + x + "\n")
    fd.close()
```

Comment: True, you have to log everything manually. This has proven very useful to me but I guess it's not very pretty.

Comment: The point was that Python has a very comprehensive `logging` package in the stdlib...